# Handling Multiple (component level) Callbacks with Redux-Sagas

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

My team started using sagas a few months ago and are loving them so far, but recently we've run into some issues with the best way to handle multiple callbacks, i.e. callbacks specific to a component that happens after the state's been updated.

So far we've hacked together two solutions, but we still think there might be an overall cleaner way.

Let's say for instance we want to show a component-specific notification the first and only the first time a user's data has been fetched.

In the first solution, we attach a callback to the action and call it in the saga after everything has succeeded. Here it is in semi-pseudocode, where this.props.loadUser dispatches an action:

```
class UserProfile extends React.Component {

  showNotification = () => {
   // notification logic
  }

  loadUser = (id) => {
    this.props.loadUser(id, this.showNotification);
  }
```

Our saga handles the callback logic something like this:

```
import api from 'utils/api';
import { receiveData } from 'modules/user';

function* fetchUserSaga(action) {
  const response = yield call(api.get,  `/users/${action.id}`);
  yield put(receiveDevice(response.data));
  if (typeof action.callback === 'function') { action.callback(); }
}
```

In the second solution, we just check if the status of the request in the state went from fetching to success and then trigger the notification from the component. Again, in semi-pseudocode:

```
class UserProfile extends React.Component {

  showNotification = () => {
   // notification logic
  }

  loadUser = (id) => {
    this.props.loadUser(id);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.status.fetchUser === 'success' && this.props.status.fetchUser !== 'success') {
      this.showNotification()
    }
  }
```

This second solution seems partly cleaner since it keeps all component logic on the component, but if we only want a notification on the first fetch, we have to add a variable to prevent that. And we have to compare props each time the component receives new ones when we know we only want to trigger the action once.

Maybe (hopefully) there's a third way we're both missing. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, I would recommend putting the notification logic in the component instead of the action. This is because showing a notification is really a presentation concern and not a data concern.

I would probably add some logic in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle function of whichever component is responsible for the notification. Basically, if `nextProps` has the data and current `props` don't, then you need to render something.

If you don't want to use the lifecycle function, you could probably still use a generic `onSuccess` callback in your action, but you should still decide whether or not to display anything from inside the component.